# Python Typeddict do not raise any err

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using typeddict and test following the doc as img below
[image]
The result should raise TypeError but it's not

[image]

I'm using python 3.10.8
I have tried several sample code but not any TypeErrors occurs
Thanks

Example i want to archive:
I want to check if the arguments passed to func example_01 is valid as declared BaseModel
I want to check it right when it passed to function, not handling it within function body

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict), and the functions docstring you've added in the question:

> TypedDict declares a dictionary type that expects all of its instances to have a certain set of keys, where each key is associated with a value of a consistent type. This expectation is not checked at runtime but is only enforced by type checkers.

Python runtime doesn't enforce these restrictions. They ought to be used as typing "hints" alone, not runtime validators.

You may want to use a type-checking / validation library, like [Pydantic](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic) to validate your objects. Here's a basic model in Pydantic:

```py
In [1]: from pydantic import BaseModel
   ...: 
   ...: class User(BaseModel):
   ...:     id: int
   ...:     name: str = "John Doe"
   ...: 

In [2]: User(name=120, id="gavin")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValidationError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File <ipython-input-8-cae6c1ea967b>:1, in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 User(name=120, id="gavin")

File ~/Desktop/projects-bench/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py:342, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__()

ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
id
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```

Read more [here](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#basic-model-usage).

Comment: I'm trying to use Pydantic as your suggestion. Do you know any way i can use it in function's argument to declare type for it

Comment: I've added an example to the answer of a Pydantic model. If that doesn't answer it, I'm not sure what you mean by function here and would need further clarification.

Comment: I've editted my post to explain my idea. Can you pls look. Thanks